# Granting Full SQL Server Permissions for a Database

Tags: sql-server, permissions, roles

How can I give a user (who was created WITHOUT LOGIN) full control over a contained database without having to specify that database's name, like GRANT CONTROL ON DATABASE::DatabaseName TO UserName, but without using a database name?  I figure it'll include GRANT ALTER ANY SCHEMA TO UserName, but I'm not sure what else I'd need to grant, or if there's a better way.  Thanks.

Comment: `user` is a loaded term here. Do you mean a Windows login, a server-level SQL Auth login, a contained user inside that db, something else? By "full control" do you mean they can do anything *in* that database (create objects, read and write data, etc.), or also anything *to* it (rename it, back it up, drop it, etc.)?

Comment: Good point.  I edited my question to mention that the user was created WITHOUT LOGIN).

Comment: I want them to be able to do anything IN that database, not TO it (per your examples).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you literally want them to be able to do *anything* in that database, you can just add them to the `db_owner` role:

```
USE ContainedDatabase;
GO
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [username];
```

If you want to be more granular, you can add them to lesser roles, like `db_ddladmin`, `db_securityadmin`, etc. You can see the list of built-in roles here:

- [Database-Level Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles)

The permissions inherent in each of those roles:

- [Permissions of Fixed Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189612(v=sql.105))

And if those don't suit, you can [create your own roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql), add your user to that role, and grant specific permissions to that role you created (and/or add them to other roles). The difference between applying the permissions to the role instead of directly to the user is simply reuse - if you add five more users that you want to apply the same permissions, you just add them to the custom role, rather than apply those granular permissions or roles to all 5 of the users.

Comment: That's just what I needed.  For completeness, could you tell me what GRANTs (without a database name) would be needed to do the same thing as adding the user to db_owner?

Comment: `GRANT CONTROL DATABASE` - that’s not exactly the same as being in `db_owner`, but it’s as close as you’re going to get. This is in the second link.

Comment: This isn't working for me, all of the tables are still locked behind select permission denied

Comment: @Morgeth888 So you add a user to the db_owner role and they still can't read a table? Something must be missing here.

Comment: yep nothing worked, made it a system admin and everything showed up. I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to your server.
2. In the Object Explorer, expand the "Security" folder under the server.
3. Right click on the "Logins" folder and choose "New Login..."
4. Add the users name in the format "Domain\UserName". You can also add domain groups by just changing it to "Domain\GroupName".
   5.If you would like this user to have full access to the SQL Server instance, you can choose the "Server Roles" tab. Adding the role "sysadmin" will give them full access to the server to do actions like update the database, backup the database, delete the database.
5. Click ok and your user will be created and have access to your database.
6. Choose the "User Mapping" tab. In the top half of this screen, check the box next to the database name. Once you highlight the database and check the box to map the user to it, you can add role memberships to the user. For access to the database.
7. Click ok and your user will be created and have access to your database.